Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "'..'" not found
Since my hosting update my PHP to 8.2 I had a lot of problems, i solve a few of them, but this still and I can't figure it out how to solve it.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "'..'" not found in /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php:61 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/widgets.php(114): WP_Widget_Factory->register(''..'') 
#1 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php(259): register_widget(''..'') 
#2 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): RevSliderFunctionsWP::{closure}('') 
#3 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) 
#4 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#5 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/widgets.php(1764): do_action('widgets_init') 
#6 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): wp_widgets_init('') 
#7 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 
#8 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#9 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-settings.php(540): do_action('init') 
#10 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/page1/...') 
#11 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/page1/...') 
#12 /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/page1/...') 
#13 /home/page1/public_html/es/index.php(17): require('/home/page1/...') 
#14 {main} thrown in /home/page1/public_html/es/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61

public function register( $widget ) {
        if ( $widget instanceof WP_Widget ) {
            $this->widgets[ spl_object_hash( $widget ) ] = $widget;
        } else {
            $this->widgets[ $widget ] = new $widget();
        }
    }

I also try to require_once a php document, but it doesn't solve it. I suppose that might be I didn't update the wordpress

You updated from PHP 8.1.29 to 8.2.21? What's your WordPress version? Have a look at: PHP Compatibility and WordPress Versions.
